# DBD::CSV: How can I generate different behavior with the two f_ext-options ".csv" and ".csv/r"?

Tags: perl, csv, dbi

This is from the DBD::File-documentation:

> f_ext
>
> This attribute is used for setting the file extension where (CSV) files are opened. There are several possibilities.

```
    DBI:CSV:f_dir=data;f_ext=.csv
```

> In this case, DBD::File will open only table.csv if both table.csv and table exist in the datadir. The table will still be named table. If your datadir has files with extensions, and you do not pass this attribute, your table is named table.csv, which is probably not what you wanted. The extension is always case-insensitive. The table names are not.

```
    DBI:CSV:f_dir=data;f_ext=.csv/r
```

> In this case the extension is required, and all filenames that do not match are ignored.

It was not possible for me to generate different behavior with the two options ".csv/r" and ".csv". Could someone show me an example, where I can see the difference between ".csv/r" and ".csv"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't seem to get it to do anything different either.  The relevant section of code is

```
sub file2table
{
    my ($data, $dir, $file, $file_is_tab, $quoted) = @_;

    $file eq "." || $file eq ".."       and return;

    my ($ext, $req) = ("", 0);
    if ($data->{f_ext}) {
        ($ext, my $opt) = split m/\//, $data->{f_ext};
        if ($ext && $opt) {
            $opt =~ m/r/i and $req = 1;
            }
        }

    (my $tbl = $file) =~ s/$ext$//i;
    $file_is_tab and $file = "$tbl$ext";

    # Fully Qualified File Name
    my $fqfn;
    unless ($quoted) { # table names are case insensitive in SQL
        opendir my $dh, $dir or croak "Can't open '$dir': $!";
        my @f = grep { lc $_ eq lc $file } readdir $dh;
        @f == 1 and $file = $f[0];
        closedir $dh or croak "Can't close '$dir': $!";
        }
    $fqfn = File::Spec->catfile ($dir, $file);

    $file = $fqfn;
    if ($ext) {
        if ($req) {
            # File extension required
            $file =~ s/$ext$//i                 or  return;
            }
        else {
            # File extension optional, skip if file with extension exists
            grep m/$ext$/i, glob "$fqfn.*"      and return;
            $file =~ s/$ext$//i;
            }
        }

    $data->{f_map}{$tbl} = $fqfn;
    return $tbl;
    } # file2table
```

Comment: Should there be a "return" if the "my @f = grep { lc $_ eq lc $file } readdir $dh;"-grep doesn't find a file?

Answer (score 1):

Does this demonstrate the difference?:

```
sandbox % echo "a,b,c" > foo
sandbox % echo "a,b,c" > foo.csv
sandbox % echo "a,b,c" > bar
sandbox % echo "a,b,c" > baz.csv
sandbox % perl -MDBI -wle'print for DBI->connect("dbi:CSV:f_ext=.csv")->tables'
"merijn".baz
"merijn".bar
"merijn".foo
sandbox % perl -MDBI -wle'print for DBI->connect("dbi:CSV:f_ext=.csv/r")->tables'
"merijn".baz
"merijn".foo
sandbox %
```

`f_ext=.csv` only makes the `.csv` a preference, but nor a requirement: in  the first case, the file "bar" with no .csv extension is still used, but "foo.csv" is chosen over "foo". With `f_ext=.csv/r"`, "bar" is ignored, as it has no ".csv" extension.

Answer (score 0):

Now in version 0.39 of DBD::File this part looks like this:

```
sub file2table
{
    my ($self, $meta, $file, $file_is_table, $respect_case) = @_;

    $file eq "." || $file eq ".."   and return; # XXX would break a possible DBD::Dir

    my ($ext, $req) = ("", 0);
    if ($meta->{f_ext}) {
    ($ext, my $opt) = split m/\//, $meta->{f_ext};
    if ($ext && $opt) {
        $opt =~ m/r/i and $req = 1;
        }
    }

    # (my $tbl = $file) =~ s/$ext$//i;
    my ($tbl, $dir, $user_spec_file);
    if ($file_is_table and defined $meta->{f_file}) {
    $tbl = $file;
    ($file, $dir, undef) = File::Basename::fileparse ($meta->{f_file});
    $user_spec_file = 1;
    }
    else {
    ($tbl, $dir, undef) = File::Basename::fileparse ($file, $ext);
    $user_spec_file = 0;
    }

    -d File::Spec->catdir ($meta->{f_dir}, $dir) or
    croak (File::Spec->catdir ($meta->{f_dir}, $dir) . ": $!");

    !$respect_case and $meta->{sql_identifier_case} == 1 and # XXX SQL_IC_UPPER
        $tbl = uc $tbl;
    !$respect_case and $meta->{sql_identifier_case} == 2 and # XXX SQL_IC_LOWER
        $tbl = lc $tbl;
    my $searchdir = File::Spec->file_name_is_absolute ($dir)
    ? $dir
    : Cwd::abs_path (File::Spec->catdir ($meta->{f_dir}, $dir));
    $searchdir eq $meta->{f_dir} and
    $dir = "";

    unless ($user_spec_file) {
    $file_is_table and $file = "$tbl$ext";

    # Fully Qualified File Name
    my $cmpsub;
    if ($respect_case) {
        $cmpsub = sub {
        my ($fn, undef, $sfx) = File::Basename::fileparse ($_, qr/\.[^.]*/);
        $fn eq $tbl and
            return (lc $sfx eq lc $ext or !$req && !$sfx);
        return 0;
        }
        }
    else {
        $cmpsub = sub {
        my ($fn, undef, $sfx) = File::Basename::fileparse ($_, qr/\.[^.]*/);
        lc $fn eq lc $tbl and
            return (lc $sfx eq lc $ext or !$req && !$sfx);
        return 0;
        }
        }

    opendir my $dh, $searchdir or croak "Can't open '$searchdir': $!";
    my @f = sort { length $b <=> length $a } grep { &$cmpsub ($_) } readdir $dh;
    @f > 0 && @f <= 2 and $file = $f[0];
    !$respect_case && $meta->{sql_identifier_case} == 4 and # XXX SQL_IC_MIXED
        ($tbl = $file) =~ s/$ext$//i;
    closedir $dh or croak "Can't close '$searchdir': $!";

    #(my $tdir = $dir) =~ s{^\./}{};    # XXX We do not want all tables to start with ./
    #$tdir and $tbl = File::Spec->catfile ($tdir, $tbl);
    $dir and $tbl = File::Spec->catfile ($dir, $tbl);

    my $tmpfn = $file;
    if ($ext) {
        if ($req) {
        # File extension required
    $tmpfn =~ s/$ext$//i            or  return;
        }
#       else {
#       # File extension optional, skip if file with extension exists
#       grep m/$ext$/i, glob "$fqfn.*"  and return;
#       $tmpfn =~ s/$ext$//i;
#       }
        }
    }

    my $fqfn = File::Spec->catfile ($searchdir, $file);
    my $fqbn = File::Spec->catfile ($searchdir, $tbl);

    $meta->{f_fqfn} = $fqfn;
    $meta->{f_fqbn} = $fqbn;
    !defined $meta->{f_lockfile} && $meta->{f_lockfile} and
    $meta->{f_fqln} = $meta->{f_fqbn} . $meta->{f_lockfile};

    $meta->{table_name} = $tbl;

    return $tbl;
    } # file2table
```

As far as I can see, the two f_ext-options are working as expected.